# How to get numbers, formatted to a fixed number of significant figures, to align in tabular using siunitx?

Tags: tables, siunitx, tabularray

I have tables of numbers with different magnitudes.  Some numbers are like 30.3542 and others are like -145283.68447.  I'd like to be able to format these with the same table setup as in my example, below. I want to limit the number of significant figures, so 30.3542 would be shown as 30.35 and -145283.68447 would be shown as -142800.  I have no preference for trailing decimal points -- with or without them is fine by me.

Edit 2023-Mar-29: I'd like to use the same `\newcolumntype` definitions for both tables.  So, I'd prefer that the `\newcolumntype` definitions don't have any arguments.

The numbers are trying to be centered, I think, but I'd prefer them to line up where the decimal point would be.  If you can get them to line up more nicely under the headings, that'd be fantastic!  It's not a problem for me if that means a decimal point is shown.

I'd rather not have to specify `table-column-width`, but that's a minor preference.
Finally, I know I've got something fouled up in my example, as I get warnings that my hboxes are overfull.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}

\newcommand{\bdr}{\ensuremath{B\cdot R}}
\newcommand{\bdt}{\ensuremath{B\cdot T}}
\newcommand{\ccc}{\ensuremath{\text{C3}}}
\newcommand{\dla}[0]{\ensuremath{\text{DLA}}}
\newcommand{\rla}[0]{\ensuremath{\text{RLA}}}
\newcommand{\lscaption}[3][1ex]{\caption[#2]{#2. \textnormal{#3}\\ \vspace{#1}}}

\newcolumntype{J}{S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]}
\newcolumntype{N}{S[scientific-notation = true, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 3, table-format=2.2e-1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\lscaption{Differences 3DOF/S vs 6DOF/S}{
comment
}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c JJN JJN }
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\rla{} (deg)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dla{} (deg)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
{LP} & {3DOF/S} & {6DOF/S} & {{$\Gamma$}} & {3DOF/S} & {6DOF/S} & {{$\Gamma$}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
5 & 350.713178054129741 & 240.210890365454204 & -0.006065115120141 & 30.791196854506090 & 10.874535168638029 & 0.005444809880985 \\
7 & 928.260620916046306 & 171.151157688540609 & -0.006205963124654 & 90.523715806238274 & 60.963950626382041 & 0.000799818279179 \\
76 & 654.530016288355160 & 294.415387871340319 & -0.009662137107410 & 76.008951214678270 & 21.007840353605254 & 0.000242347374590 \\
75 & 156.612347494337982 & 362.604374274472301 & -0.060612906449607 & 48.264341469864183 & 36.951974409626670 & -0.000640833734826 \\
25 & 122.284569715601792 & 266.533453573082600 & -0.000142667548177 & 48.790634972518796 & 13.919652659616654 & 0.006431814046446 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:diffc7}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\lscaption{Differences 3DOF/S vs 6DOF/S}{
comment
}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c JJN JJN }
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bdt{} (km)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bdr{} (km)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
{LP} & {3DOF/S} & {6DOF/S} & {{$\Gamma$}} & {3DOF/S} & {6DOF/S} & {{$\Gamma$}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
2 & -68366.072508240821589 & -47940.593376982723440 & 33425.690144507067478 & 25106.437204604970658 & 3735.270218521665689 & -8135.119969136036299 \\
4 & -43224.208042785342132 & -82570.875759750888465 & 71790.620372230230829 & 24070.884249127772596 & 14813.315829007065580 & -9215.266000230855832 \\
92 & -93558.194401149489926 & -10061.267567114861153 & 8883.660889289663099 & 56694.540725077379747 & 84976.987983216390581 & -5522.007654219346814 \\
93 & -709072.534593535004289 & -68379.506859346867373 & 15207.051039394738680 & 23861.831954689827338 & 41609.705691851832597 & -9424.584740471677877 \\
95 & -979112.989370272739695 & -324434.742112474223309 & 4950.783283617139435 & 41097.048921156019871 & 69835.190677535146849 & -7379.565733537314698 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:diffbdt}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output for tabular]

@User23456234 mentioned using `tabularray`.  Here is a working example with `tabularray` -- it is a general improvement, but it doesn't alleviate my formatting concerns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\newcommand{\bdr}{\ensuremath{B\cdot R}}
\newcommand{\bdt}{\ensuremath{B\cdot T}}
\newcommand{\ccc}{\ensuremath{\text{C3}}}
\newcommand{\dla}[0]{\ensuremath{\text{DLA}}}
\newcommand{\rla}[0]{\ensuremath{\text{RLA}}}
\newcommand{\lscaption}[3][1ex]{\caption[#2]{#2. \textnormal{#3}\\ \vspace{#1}}}

\newcolumntype{J}{S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]}
\newcolumntype{N}{S[scientific-notation = true, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 3, table-format=2.2e-1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\lscaption{Differences 3DOF/S vs 6DOF/S}{
comment
}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={
      l
      S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]
      S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]
      S[scientific-notation = true, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 3, table-format=2.2e-1]
      S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]
      S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]
      S[scientific-notation = true, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 3, table-format=2.2e-1]
      },
    cell{1}{2,5} = {c=3}{c},
    }
\toprule
  & {{{\rla{} (deg)}}} & &  & {{{\dla{} (deg)}}} & &  \\
\cmidrule[lr]{2-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
{{{LP}}} & {{{3DOF/S}}} & {{{6DOF/S}}} & {{{$\Gamma$}}} & {{{3DOF/S}}} & {{{6DOF/S}}} & {{{$\Gamma$}}} \\
\cmidrule[lr]{2-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
5 & 350.713178054129741 & 240.210890365454204 & -0.006065115120141 & 30.791196854506090 & 10.874535168638029 & 0.005444809880985 \\
7 & 928.260620916046306 & 171.151157688540609 & -0.006205963124654 & 90.523715806238274 & 60.963950626382041 & 0.000799818279179 \\
76 & 654.530016288355160 & 294.415387871340319 & -0.009662137107410 & 76.008951214678270 & 21.007840353605254 & 0.000242347374590 \\
75 & 156.612347494337982 & 362.604374274472301 & -0.060612906449607 & 48.264341469864183 & 36.951974409626670 & -0.000640833734826 \\
25 & 122.284569715601792 & 266.533453573082600 & -0.000142667548177 & 48.790634972518796 & 13.919652659616654 & 0.006431814046446 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\label{tbl:diffc7}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\lscaption{Differences 3DOF/S vs 6DOF/S}{
comment
}
\small
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={
      l
      S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]
      S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]
      S[scientific-notation = true, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 3, table-format=2.2e-1]
      S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]
      S[table-column-width=48pt, round-mode=figures, round-precision = 4, scientific-notation = false, drop-zero-decimal=false]
      S[scientific-notation = true, round-mode = figures, round-precision = 3, table-format=2.2e-1]
      },
    cell{1}{2,5} = {c=3}{c},
    }
\toprule
  & {{{\bdt{} (km)}}} & & & {{{\bdr{} (km)}}} & &  \\
\cmidrule[lr]{2-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
{{{LP}}} & {{{3DOF/S}}} & {{{6DOF/S}}} & {{{$\Gamma$}}} & {{{3DOF/S}}} & {{{6DOF/S}}} & {{{$\Gamma$}}} \\
\cmidrule[lr]{2-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
2 & -68366.072508240821589 & -47940.593376982723440 & 33425.690144507067478 & 25106.437204604970658 & 3735.270218521665689 & -8135.119969136036299 \\
4 & -43224.208042785342132 & -82570.875759750888465 & 71790.620372230230829 & 24070.884249127772596 & 14813.315829007065580 & -9215.266000230855832 \\
92 & -93558.194401149489926 & -10061.267567114861153 & 8883.660889289663099 & 56694.540725077379747 & 84976.987983216390581 & -5522.007654219346814 \\
93 & -709072.534593535004289 & -68379.506859346867373 & 15207.051039394738680 & 23861.831954689827338 & 41609.705691851832597 & -9424.584740471677877 \\
95 & -979112.989370272739695 & -324434.742112474223309 & 4950.783283617139435 & 41097.048921156019871 & 69835.190677535146849 & -7379.565733537314698 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\label{tbl:diffbdt}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: my tables with tabularray]

For example, the number "3735" is not aligned with the number below it.  I want the ones place of "3735" to be
just above the ones place of "14810"

Here's what I'm looking for. The yellow
boxes are only there to highlight the columns
which I changed.

[image: desired result with highlights]

Comment: the `tabularray` package has an `siunitx` library

Comment: @User23456234, using `tabularray` is a general improvement, but it doesn't address my questions about formatting

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the key `table-column-width=48pt`, but instead specify the number of digits you need.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={bf}]{caption}

\newcommand{\bdr}{\ensuremath{B\cdot R}}
\newcommand{\bdt}{\ensuremath{B\cdot T}}
\newcommand{\ccc}{\ensuremath{\text{C3}}}
\newcommand{\dla}[0]{\ensuremath{\text{DLA}}}
\newcommand{\rla}[0]{\ensuremath{\text{RLA}}}
\newcommand{\lscaption}[2]{\caption[#1]{#1. \textnormal{#2}}}

\newcolumntype{J}[1]{S[
  table-format=#1,
  round-mode=figures,
  round-precision = 4,
  scientific-notation = false,
  drop-zero-decimal=false
]}
\newcolumntype{N}[1]{S[
  scientific-notation = true,
  round-mode = figures,
  round-precision = 3,
  table-format=#1
]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\lscaption{Differences 3DOF/S vs 6DOF/S}{
comment
}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  c
  J{3.1}
  J{3.1}
  N{-1.2e-1}
  J{2.2}
  J{2.2}
  N{-1.2e-1}
}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\rla{} (deg)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dla{} (deg)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
{LP} & {3DOF/S} & {6DOF/S} & {{$\Gamma$}} & {3DOF/S} & {6DOF/S} & {{$\Gamma$}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
 5 & 350.713178054129741 & 240.210890365454204 & -0.006065115120141 & 30.791196854506090 & 10.874535168638029 & 0.005444809880985 \\
 7 & 928.260620916046306 & 171.151157688540609 & -0.006205963124654 & 90.523715806238274 & 60.963950626382041 & 0.000799818279179 \\
76 & 654.530016288355160 & 294.415387871340319 & -0.009662137107410 & 76.008951214678270 & 21.007840353605254 & 0.000242347374590 \\
75 & 156.612347494337982 & 362.604374274472301 & -0.060612906449607 & 48.264341469864183 & 36.951974409626670 & -0.000640833734826 \\
25 & 122.284569715601792 & 266.533453573082600 & -0.000142667548177 & 48.790634972518796 & 13.919652659616654 & 0.006431814046446 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:diffc7}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\lscaption{Differences 3DOF/S vs 6DOF/S}{
comment
}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  c
  J{-6.0}
  J{-6.0}
  N{1.2e1}
  J{5.0}
  J{5.0}
  N{-1.2e1}
}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bdt{} (km)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bdr{} (km)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
{LP} & {3DOF/S} & {6DOF/S} & {{$\Gamma$}} & {3DOF/S} & {6DOF/S} & {{$\Gamma$}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
2 & -68366.072508240821589 & -47940.593376982723440 & 33425.690144507067478 & 25106.437204604970658 & 3735.270218521665689 & -8135.119969136036299 \\
4 & -43224.208042785342132 & -82570.875759750888465 & 71790.620372230230829 & 24070.884249127772596 & 14813.315829007065580 & -9215.266000230855832 \\
92 & -93558.194401149489926 & -10061.267567114861153 & 8883.660889289663099 & 56694.540725077379747 & 84976.987983216390581 & -5522.007654219346814 \\
93 & -709072.534593535004289 & -68379.506859346867373 & 15207.051039394738680 & 23861.831954689827338 & 41609.705691851832597 & -9424.584740471677877 \\
95 & -979112.989370272739695 & -324434.742112474223309 & 4950.783283617139435 & 41097.048921156019871 & 69835.190677535146849 & -7379.565733537314698 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:diffbdt}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that you added arguments to column types `J` & `N`. Do you think there's a solution where the same fixed `\newcolumntype` definitions (no args) are applied to each table, as I was trying to do in my MWE?  (I had tried to make this part of my question, but I didn't do a good job of it)